# Create animation for tap to focus using SwiftyCams didFocusAtPoint function

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftycam

I am using SwiftyCam and would like to give some sort of animated feedback when using the tap to focus feature.

SwiftyCam comes with a didFocusAtPoint function which is called when the screen is tapped and provides you with the point of the tap.

How can I now create and show an animation at that point?

```
func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didFocusAtPoint point: CGPoint) {
     // Called when a user initiates a tap gesture on the preview layer
     // Will only be called if tapToFocus = true
     // Returns a CGPoint of the tap location on the preview layer
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?, This is primarily an implementation detail open to opinion-based interpretation. Your question should solve a unique, and verifiable problem see [Asking Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I tried creating a UIView and setting its frame using the x and y coordinates from point. I then used UIVIew.animateWithDuration to dismiss the newly added view after a few seconds. When I ran nothing happened though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DemoSwiftyCam` project on [Github](https://github.com/Awalz/SwiftyCam) already has an implementation for this feature:

**ViewController.swift**

```
func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didFocusAtPoint point: CGPoint) {
    print("Did focus at point: \(point)")
    focusAnimationAt(point)
}
```

...

```
extension ViewController {

///...


fileprivate func focusAnimationAt(_ point: CGPoint) {
    let focusView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "focus")) // Image Available in DemoSwiftyCam Assets.xcassets
    focusView.center = point
    focusView.alpha = 0.0
    view.addSubview(focusView)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        focusView.alpha = 1.0
        focusView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.25, y: 1.25)
    }) { (success) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            focusView.alpha = 0.0
            focusView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.6, y: 0.6)
        }) { (success) in
            focusView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```